# How do i extract an array from this plist dictionary?

Tags: ios, arrays, nsdictionary, plist

How do i extract 'choices' from the first 'Item 0' into an array?
[image]

At the moment, printing the array gives null.

```
 NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pollData" ofType:@"plist"]];

    NSMutableArray *arrayOfChoices = [[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Item 0"] objectForKey:@"choices"];
    self.dataArray = arrayOfChoices;

    NSLog(@"array: %@", self.dataArray);
```

Comment: Well for one thing, it's not an array. And more importantly, `dataDictionary` isn't a dictionary; the root object is an array.

Comment: sorry i overlooked that. but i changed it to an array and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Changed what to an array?

Comment: The 'choices' Dictionary in the plist.

Comment: ok thanks. yes i shouldve looked at that more closely sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root object is an array, not a dictionary.

```
NSArray * pollData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pollData" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

The object at index 0 in that array is a dictionary, as is the object inside that which is keyed to `@"choices"`.

```
NSDictionary * choices = [[pollData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"choices"];
```

Objects that are unserialized from plists are never mutable. If you want a mutable dictionary, you need to make a mutable copy.